# How to place the figure at the bottom of page in latex?

Tags: latex, figure

I am having problem in placing the figure at the bottom of page in latex. When I specify the `\begin{figure*}[b]`, all the figures in my documents goes at the end of document. What I need is just place one specific figure at the bottom of current page or next page.

Please guide me how can I do this?

Comment: Before we can do that, can you provide your `\documentclass`? Do you have a document in `twoside` mode? Perhaps better even, provide a minimal example that replicates the current faulty behaviour you're experiencing. Perhaps the image you want to place at the bottom is too large? You need to spoonfeed us information in order for the community to answer your question.

Comment: \begin{figure*}[b]
    \includegraphics[scale =0.8]{graphics/myfig.eps}
    \caption{Analysis of failures, (a) total failures, (b) failure per year (c) downtime  (d) time between the failures,  a small fraction of failures which occur beyond the x-axis scale are not shown. }
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure*}

Comment: It is to mention further that the figure is rightly placed at top of page. but I need it to be placed at the bottom of page. but when I add [b] parameter, all the figures in my document goes at the end of document.

Comment: The document class is \documentclass{ieeeaccess}

Comment: I need the figure to print on two columns, not in just one column, as the figure size does not fit in one column. Just to try I also used \begin{figure}[b]...\end{figure} but it results in the same issue and did not solve the problem

Comment: Well, one really has to drag the information out of you... like pulling teeth! See [Put a `table*` at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3527/5764) It's the same problem, only using the `table` float.

Comment: For future reference, please provide the community with a minimal work example - see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) - that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what your issue is. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow the community to replicate your behaviour. It puts the questioner and the community on the same page and speeds up getting solutions to the interested parties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to place a float at the bottom of a two-column document, you can use the [`dblfloatfix` package](//ctan.org/pkg/dblfloatfix). From the brief package description:

> The pack­age solves two prob­lems: floats in a twocol­umn doc­u­ment come out in the right order and al­lowed float po­si­tions are now `[tbp]`.

So, after `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` you can use

```
\begin{figure*}[btp]
  % <your figure here>
\end{figure*}
```

Like will all floats (especially in a `two-column` environment), the float may not end up where it is placed. As such, you may have to move around the `figure*` declaration to achieve the desired location within your document.

[`stfloats`](//ctan.org/pkg/stfloats) provides a similar functionality.

Reference: [Put a `table*` at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3527/5764)

Comment: did not work for me!

Comment: @PascalIv: If so, consider asking a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) over on [tex.se].

Answer (score 10):

Using `\begin{figure*}[!b]` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Werner's solutions didn't actually work for me.

So I just used this -

```
\begin{figure*}[b]
  % <your figure here>
\end{figure*}
```

source: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures

Comment: For me, the other solutions didn't work, and this solution didn't work either :)